# Migrate Rails app with passenger, capistrano(with rubber), and ImageMagick to Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, phusion-passenger, capistrano, dreamhost

I have a beta app that a developer has made for my company and I need to clone their work onto another server.

I have successfully backed up the MySQL database to another server and copied all their files over. They are running it as "betaQ. They have four revisions with the "current" sym link pointing to the latest like this:

```
shared (86 ruby gems installed @ \bundle\ruby\1.9.1\gems)
current (sym link
releases
   \20130201
   \20130202
   \20130203
   \20130204
```

I don't believe I need all those gems.

I copied the files over many times to my personal host (Dreamhost) and another host account through my company (SoftLayer) and each time failed in one way or another.

I have 0 background in ruby. I need to get this clone up and running first (urgent priority) and get a working knowledge of all the aspects of ruby second.

I guess I need some hand-holding here.

Answer (score 0):

A Rails >= 3.0 web application is always **self contained** (files included in the most recent capistranized release and with symlinks to shared). So, moving it as-is is always safe and if the starting and if the end server satisfy the same exact software requirements - same operating system, same ruby version - you don't even need to recompile or reinstall gems.

So, you copied it on another server and where's the problem? Does the webserver refuse to load it? With which error?